# Openning a program in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have downloaded a package, written in c++, which included example programs that I want to open and run. Should I make a new project for every program and add 'manually' the header files? or is there another automatic method.

Comment: You can add a virtual folder to a project (it just points to a another folder in the file system)...